# Webserver: chrooted PHP gives mysql.sock error when attempting to reach mysql

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, php, chroot

I have configured an Ubuntu webserver with Nginx + PHP5-FPM. I have created a chrooted environment (using jailkit) that I'm tossing my developers into, from where they can develop their test applications.

Chroot jail:
/home/jail

Nginx and PHP5-FPM run outside the chroot, but are configured to function with websites within the chrooted environment.

So far, Nginx and PHP5-FPM are serving up files without issue, except for the following:
When attempting to connect to MySQL, we receive this error: **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'**

Now, I believe the issue is due to the non-chrooted php.ini referencing mysqld.sock outside of the chroot environment (it's actually using the MySQL default setting currently).

**My question is, how can I configure PHP to access MySQL via loopback or similar? (Found that as a suggestion in a google result, but without any instructions)**

Or if I'm missing some other obvious setting, let me know. If there's an option of creating a hardlink (that would remain available even if mysql is restarted), that would be handy as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved my own issue.
Jailkit couldn't create a hard link reference to mysqld.sock, as Ubuntu stores /var/run in tmpfs, which appears to the system to be a separate partition (which breaks hardlink functionality).
I instead am now mounting /var/run/mysqld in the jail now, like so:
`mount --bind /var/run/mysqld /home/jail/var/run/mysqld/`

Comment: Is it possible to script this when creating the jail?

Answer (score 4):

How about using as `host` value `127.0.0.1`? It uses TCP connection which doesn't write socket (unlike `localhost` value on unix).

Comment: Wasting system resources for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Remounting using `--bind` for the chroot looks like a workable suggestion.  However, IMHO connecting to MySQL using a TCP socket (127.0.0.1) seems cleaner, more secure and less likely to go wrong.

The reason I say that is that various sources including http://blog.dispatched.ch/postfix-and-mysql-debian/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389214/postfix-cant-connect-with-mysql-table-when-using-unix-socket-postmap-succeeds suggest adding to the fstab:

```
 /var/run/mysqld /home/jail/var/run/mysqld bind defaults,bind 0 0
```

Be cautious with that: Debian at least cleans out /var/run on reboot, so the mount will fail at boot time, and so will your service.  Of course you could instead use:

```
 /var/run /home/jail/var/run bind defaults,bind 0 0
```

Comment: Works like a charm. But really ... it there no easier solution? Why does MySQL need a socket at all, when the communication runs via localhost:3306, anyway?

Comment: Okay, found out it IS easier (https://serverfault.com/a/337844/100194), just use an IP address (`127.0.0.1`) as MySQL host in mysqli_connect(), instead of `localhost`. This requires slightly more resources, but the difference should be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

You can control MySQL's socket via the socket option in your my.cnf file.

```
socket = /home/jail/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: That's a valid suggestion, but my concern is that /home/jail could be "volatile". Any suggestion on how to modify /etc/jailkit/jk_init.ini to force jailkit to create a hardlink to the mysqld.sock file, or some other jailkit compatible solution that doesn't risk the MySQL server if the jail is (for instance) completely deleted and rebuilt?