# How to force MySQL to connect by TCP instead of a Unix socket?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, connection, localhost, socket

I would like to analyze `mysql` traffic. Right now, all mysql requests are sent to the MySQL unix socket:

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3734388  15304/mysqld        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I'm trying to disable that socket to force MySQL to use the network socket instead on the loopback. I tried commenting out all the `socket` directives in the `my.cnf` and `debian.cnf` files and restarted MySQL but it made no difference.

**How can I disable the MySQL unix socket to force MySQL over the network?**

additional info: I'm running `MySQL 5.1` on `ubuntu 10.04`.

**Precisions on the question**
Since plenty of people suggested enabling the network socket I would like to clarify my question by pointing out that the bind address was already enabled with `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` and that a listening connection is available:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15601/mysqld
```

Still I see no connections attempt to `127.0.0.1:3306` coming from my webapp (Drupal website).

**Updated with the answer**

It appears indeed that the issue is coming from the `mysqli` connector that Drupal uses (in `.ht_config.php` for those who are interested). It was set:  `mysqli://drupal:***@localhost/drupal`, changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` fixed the issue (i.e. Drupal is now making connections to the network socket).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In Linux and other *nixes, MySQL will assume you want to use a [socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) (Unix domain socket) if you connect to the host "localhost" (which would be the default hostname).

You can override this in 3 ways:

1. Specify a different hostname like 127.0.0.1 (`mysql -h 127.0.0.1`) or your server's real hostname
2. Specify that you want to use TCP and not a socket (`mysql --protocol tcp`)

You can also easily make that the default my editing your my.cnf so it has this ([client] means any client:

```
[client]
protocol=tcp
```

You can see the full description of how MySQL decides how to connect here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Does running the MySQL server inside a Docker container with docker-compose with the use of the container name as its host name forces the use of the network protocl over a socket protocol ?

Comment: defintiely should be the accepted answer. way 3 (protocol=tcp in my.cnf) is the only way that works without any additional command line parameters so works without changes in any script.

Answer (score 64):

Use an IP-binding to **`127.0.0.1`**. That should activate a listening port on `localhost`. On the client side do not use `localhost` - use `127.0.0.1` instead. Many clients have an internal alias that makes them connect to the socket if you specify `localhost` as target.

MySQL is strange.

Comment: Just use `--protocol`.. see Jonathan's answer.

Answer (score 17):

Isn't this really a client issue ? If using the mysql program You can use the `--protocol` switch. From the man page

```
 --protocol={TCP|SOCKET|PIPE|MEMORY}

       The connection protocol to use for connecting to the server. It is
       useful when the other connection parameters normally would cause a
       protocol to be used other than the one you want. For details on the
       allowable values, see Section 4.2.2, “Connecting to the MySQL
       Server”.
```

I just tried

```
mysql --protocol=TCP -u root -p
```

whilst monitoring port 3306 with `tcpdump -i lo tcp port 3306` and I can see traffic whereas if I just run

```
mysql  -u root -p
```

I (correctly) see no traffic on port 3306.

EDIT:

Now that you tell us you are using DRUPAL, the solution is relatively easy.

Go to `sites/<sitename>` or `sites/default` and edit the `settings.php` file

You will find a structure like this

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'databasename',
      'username' => 'databaseuser',
      'password' => 'databasepassword',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Change the `'localhost'` to `'127.0.0.1'` and save the file.

Comment: it could indeed by a client issue but since the client is a web application (Drupal) and I have no control over it I was looking for a way to force it from a system standpoint.

Comment: well by saying `no control` I was being dramatic. I could modify the `.ht_config.php` file and fix the issue.

Comment: A tad dramatic perhaps but it is a client issue and it is easily solved. See my edit.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question with the answer after I added my comment. For some reason we are using `.ht_config.php` instead of `settings.php`. I don't know why (the dev team requested it should be that way). Now the issue is that Drupal seems to be reading the `.ht_config.php` file on every request (because if I change it, changes are immediately taken into account) which can't help with the performances. We will be looking for a way to cache those settings at application layer but that's a different problem.

Comment: Note: you can't do `--protocol=socket` if you have a `host` entry in the `[client]` section of `.my.cnf` it gives `wrong or unknown protocol` error.  (mysql 5.7.13)

Answer (score 1):

This may sound a little crazy

Try setting the socket file to an absolute path whose path resides on another machine

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_socket

Otherwise, you cannot bypass this default behavior because a socket file must exist for mysqld to communicate with.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the my.cnf and add the directive

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

or your preferred IP to make it accessible over network. Restart mysql after to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

php mysqli client will use unix socket file instead of tcp network when you pass in the NULL value or the string "localhost"(http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

it seems that sqlyog client always use tcp network even when you fill "localhost" in it

Answer (score -1):

I had to delete /etc/my.cnf (after backing it up), then restarted the server. Then I could connect with a socket and the error disappeared.

Comment: This does not answer the question.