# Cannot acces to localhost mysql server. ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have inherited an ubuntu machine with mysql installed and I don't know how. My problem is that i can't access to mysql.

Here some info of my host:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

MySQl version `mysql  Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

This is error message:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

---

$ service mysqld start
Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found.
```

This file `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` dosn't exist.

**EDIT WITH MORE INFO**

```
$ netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      99/systemd-resolved
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      136/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      303/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      313/sshd: root@pts/
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      138/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      136/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      303/master
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      313/sshd: root@pts/
```

```
$ systemctl start mysql
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
$ systemctl status mysql.service
* mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-01-27 08:32:50 CET; 10s ago
    Process: 5687 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 5696 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 5696 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 2 (No such file or directory)

Jan 27 08:32:50 osticket systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 27 08:32:50 osticket systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 27 08:32:50 osticket systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jan 27 08:32:50 osticket systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jan 27 08:32:50 osticket systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 27 08:32:50 osticket systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 27 08:32:50 osticket systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 27 08:32:50 osticket systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

```
$ pwd && ls
/var/log
alternatives.log       apache2        auth.log.4.gz  dpkg.log.1     lastlog        mysqld.err            php7.4-fpm.log.2.gz  php7.4-fpm.log.8.gz  syslog.3.gz           wtmp
alternatives.log.1     apt            btmp           dpkg.log.2.gz  mail.log       php7.4-fpm.log        php7.4-fpm.log.3.gz  php7.4-fpm.log.9.gz  syslog.4.gz           wtmp.1
alternatives.log.2.gz  auth.log       btmp.1         dpkg.log.3.gz  mail.log.1     php7.4-fpm.log.1      php7.4-fpm.log.4.gz  private              syslog.5.gz
alternatives.log.3.gz  auth.log.1     dist-upgrade   dpkg.log.4.gz  mail.log.2.gz  php7.4-fpm.log.10.gz  php7.4-fpm.log.5.gz  syslog               syslog.6.gz
alternatives.log.4.gz  auth.log.2.gz  dmesg          faillog        mail.log.3.gz  php7.4-fpm.log.11.gz  php7.4-fpm.log.6.gz  syslog.1             syslog.7.gz
alternatives.log.5.gz  auth.log.3.gz  dpkg.log       journal        mail.log.4.gz  php7.4-fpm.log.12.gz  php7.4-fpm.log.7.gz  syslog.2.gz          ubuntu-advantage.log
```

```
$ cat /var/log/mysqld.err
2022-01-26T12:23:07.952718Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010083] [Server] --verbose is for use with --help; did you mean --log-error-verbosity?
2022-01-26T12:23:07.952814Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010095] [Server] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
2022-01-26T12:23:07.953735Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

```
$ namei -l /var/lib/mysql-files
f: /var/lib/mysql-files
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root var
drwxr-xr-x root root lib
                     mysql-files - No such file or directory
```

I have tried to fix it in many ways but I can't. Someone could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the content of `/var/log/daemon.log`?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen `/var/log/daemon.log` file don't exist on my host.

Comment: What files does `/var/log` contain? It is very odd that `daemon.log` is not there, that is the standard log target in Ubuntu and many other Linux distributions.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Now you can see the files of `/var/log` on the question

Comment: `/var/log/mysqld.err`?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider nothing interesting in `/var/log/mysqld.err`. You can see on question.

Comment: You have a strange definition of "interesting". Did you check `/var/lib/mysql-files`? Please show `namei -l /var/lib/mysql-files`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider There is no `/var/lib/mysql-files`. You can see the output of `namei -l /var/lib/mysql-files` on the question.

Comment: Let's go back a bit. You have inherited this machine. What is the exact purpose of the machine and what is your objective? It clearly has some non-working install of MySQL. Unless the use case known, it is fruitless to diagnose the MySQL setup issue.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen There are an app that has been unused for a long time. Now I've been asked to get it back up and running, and the app uses a database. So, I'm trying to run again, but i have this issue with DB.

Comment: The problem here is that this database hasn't been working when the app was taken offline. The data directory for MySQL was non-existent, so there is no data for the app. You need to verify is this really the DB host that the app used. If not, then you need to find the correct host.

Answer (score 1):

Your mysqld does not start and states the following error in the error log:

> Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files

`/var/lib/mysql-files` is missing, so you need to create it.

```bash
sudo install -o mysql -g mysql -m 0700 -d /var/lib/mysql-files
```

Afterwards you should be able to start the mysqld using `systemctl start mysql`.

Comment: I have created `/var/lib/mysql-files` like you say and now I have it `drwx------  2 mysql   mysql   4096 Jan 27 13:45 mysql-files`. Then start mysqld using `systemctl start mysql`, but I have the same error `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code`. ;(

Comment: Please. Read the error log.

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -tlpn` - is the `mysql` running on port 3306? or elsewhere? by default the connection to localhost are via a socket try add `--protocol 3306` - see [How to force MySQL to connect by TCP instead of a Unix socket?](https://serverfault.com/questions/337818/how-to-force-mysql-to-connect-by-tcp-instead-of-a-unix-socket) - also, `ps ax | grep mysql` and then `lsof -p <mysqld pid>` and look for IPv4 or IPv6 or socket - the socket may be placed on a different place than where the client expects it.

Comment: I put the info of `netstat -tlpn` on the question. I can't see nothing about mysql

Comment: what about `ps ax | grep mysql` ? is it even running?

Comment: `ps ax | grep mysql` this is output `2445 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto  mysql`

Comment: netstat -t is not a reliable way to determine if MySQL is running - it can run quite quite happily and be fully functional without having any network sockets open

Answer (score 0):

The service name is `mysql` in Debian / Ubuntu, so you need to use `systemctl start mysql` to start the server.

Comment: With `systemctl start mysql` is also give me a error. With `systemctl start mysql` is also give me an error. I puted more info in the question.